# I'm iterating a dynamic object using "*ngFor" and "Keyvalue" pipe. object has one array of obj need to display that too

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm developing an angular app and i have to loop through object which looks like this

`{
  "id":"0",
  "practiceName":null,
  "phone":"201-224-6430",
  "billingAccounts":[{
                     "number":"10-140195"
                    }]
}`

I have used keyvalue pipe in ng for as follows

```
       *ngFor="let item of user | keyvalue"
        <label>{{item.key}} </label>
        <p> {{item.value}} </p>
```

im getting output as follows

`billingAccounts [object Object]

 id 0 
 phone 201-224-6430`

i need to loop through the array

`billingAccounts 'number':"10-140195"`
like this kindly help out

Answer (score 2):

Using ngTemplate, see the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psoppe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="value;context:{$implicit:user}"></ng-container>

<ng-template #value let-object>
    <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
        <ng-container *ngIf="isArray(item.value)">
      <p>{{item.key}}:</p>
      <div style="'margin-left':10rem" *ngFor="let element of item.value">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="value;context:{$implicit:element}"></ng-container>
      </div>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="!isArray(item.value)">
            <p><label>{{item.key}} </label>
         {{item.value}} 
      </p>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Update** I forgot say that we need a function isArray in .ts

```
isArray(variable:any)
{
    return Array.isArray(variable)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the value is an array.

The fastest (but ugliest) way to make it work would be

```
<label>{{item.key}} </label>
<p *ngIf="item.key !== 'billlingAccounts'; else billingAccounts"> {{item.value}} </p>
<ng-template #billingAccounts>
  <p *ngFor="let billing of item.value">
    {{ billing.number }}
  </p>
</ng-template>
```

But then again, it's very ugly and a terrible practice.

Other than that, you should provide a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue and specify the end goal to get better help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of user | keyvalue">
     <span *ngIf="item.key === 'billingAccounts'; else elsePart"> 
       <div *ngFor="let data of item.value; let i = index;">
        <label>{{data.number}} </label>
       </div>
     </span>
     <ng-template #elsePart>
         <label>{{item.key}} </label>
          <p> {{item.value}} </p>
     </ng-template>

</div>
```